# Fix "login failed for user.." error in connecting Microsoft SQL server in Python

Tags: python, sql-server

I am receiving a very common error while trying to connect Microsoft SQL Server using `pyodbc`. I've tried the solutions suggested here before, but none of them solved my problem.

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server= server_name;'
                      'Database= database_name;'     
                      'UID= user_id;'
                      'PWD= password;')


InterfaceError: ('28000', "[28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]
Login failed for user ' '. (18456) (SQLDriverConnect); [28000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]
[SQL Server]Login failed for user ' '. (18456)")
```

When I connect the database via `Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18` app, below is how I connect. I copy and paste server name, login, and password information to my Python code as shown above. My OS is Windows 10. When I call `select @@version`, I get `Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-GDR) (KB4583463)...`

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admittedly my python skills are not the best but I'm suspicious of all the single quotes in your connection string.

In the error message `Login failed for user ' '` is that blank value for the use what you *actually* see or have you stripped that out?  If that's what you actually see then I think your connection string is malformed.

Refer to the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/python/pyodbc/step-3-proof-of-concept-connecting-to-sql-using-pyodbc?view=sql-server-ver15&WT.mc_id=DP-MVP-5001259#connect) for how to build out a connection string.

Comment: Just figured it out a minute ago and came here to delete the post. It tuned out, you already posted the answer :)